# Why YUI ToolTip can't on top in JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, tooltip, yui

I try to show some tooltip on MsChart which is on the jQuery Dialog but the tooltip never on top of dialog. 
Below is my total source code.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 640,
            height: 'auto',
            position: [100, 110]
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < $('area').length; i++) {

            $('area:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id', 'area-id-' + i); //change id 
            $.data(this, 'area-title-' + i, $('area:eq(' + i + ')').attr('title')); //store title 

            if ($.data(this, 'area-title-' + i) != undefined) {

                new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip("myTip", {
                    context: 'area-id-' + i,
                    text: "hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>",
                    width: 300,
                    container: this.dialog2,
                    autodismissdelay: 3600000, // show one hour 
                    showdelay: 0
                });
            }
        }
    });

</script>

<div id="dialog2" title="my chart">
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
</div>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> rom_list = new List<string>();
        rom_list.Add("1.1");
        rom_list.Add("1.2");
        rom_list.Add("1.3");
        rom_list.Add("1.4");
        rom_list.Add("1.5");

        List<double> value_list = new List<double>();
        value_list.Add(4);
        value_list.Add(2);
        value_list.Add(6);
        value_list.Add(3);
        value_list.Add(8);

        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(rom_list, value_list);

        foreach (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint point in Chart1.Series[0].Points)
        {
            point.ToolTip = "this is tooltip " + point.YValues[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery modal dialog styles has z-index thay bigger that tooltips has

more detial about this css see hee http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

in order to solve it you need change your css of tooltip or jquery model dialog

Comment: it works, you realy solve my problem. many thanks for your help.